# Adobe Photoshop CS5 PC version running via boot camp

Tags: bootcamp, parallels-desktop, adobe-photoshop

I just bought my first MacBook Pro as I will be doing more work on the road, but I just realized my Windows license of Photoshop CS5 won't work on my Mac.  I guess it's OS-based?  Someone suggested installing Boot Camp or Parallels to run Windows via the Mac and use my Windows Photoshop CS5 license that way.

Anyone ever tried this?  If not, I guess it'll be GIMP for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Parallels is fantastic. You can either install Windows to a Bootcamp partition (so you have the option of booting straight into Windows), or just as a virtual machine. Either way, Parallels can then run in "Coherence Mode", which will allow Photoshop to appear on your Mac desktop as though it were a native application. I use Parallels for developing Windows software and for games, and the performance is brilliant.

Of course, you could talk to Adobe about a crossgrade to the Mac version - if you don't already own Windows the cost may be comparable.

Comment: +1: I'd call to the Adobe support first. And only to inform about the alternatives: VMware Fusion is a viable alternative to Parallels; just don't ask anyone which is better.